# Grafana Dashboard - Change {Server,Server,Server}?

Tags: powershell, grafana, dashboard, influxdb, telegraf

I'm attempting to learn more about Grafana (Influx & Telegraf) in my lab environment but I'm unsuccessful in changing the {Server,Server,Server} to Server,Server,Server (See screenshots & code)

What am I doing wrong? I want to see multiple servers at once but not their values lumped together...

I'd like to have...

Server1 - Error
Server2 - Error
Server1- Successful
Server2 - Successful

And not...

Server1,Server2 - Error
Server1,Server2 - Successful

[Grafana Dashboard 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OVPa.png)

[Grafana Dashboard 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mzLo.png)

[Powershell Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGDxU.png)

PowerShell Script

```
# Parameters
$Server = 'localhost'
$Database = 'CM_ORG'

# Query
$sqlCmd = "
SELECT      [$($Database)].[dbo].[DistributionPoints].ServerName AS DistributionPoint,
            [$($Database)].[dbo].[ContentDistributionByDP].NumberErrors AS Errors,
            [$($Database)].[dbo].[ContentDistributionByDP].NumberInProgress AS InProgress,
            [$($Database)].[dbo].[ContentDistributionByDP].NumberInstalled AS Installed,
            [$($Database)].[dbo].[ContentDistributionByDP].NumberUnknown AS Unknown

FROM        [$($Database)].[dbo].[ContentDistributionByDP]

LEFT JOIN [$($Database)].[dbo].[DistributionPoints] ON [$($Database)].[dbo].[ContentDistributionByDP].DPID = [$($Database)].[dbo].[DistributionPoints].DPID
"

# Run
Try { $Result = Invoke-Sqlcmd $sqlCmd -Server $Server -Database $Database -OutputSqlErrors $False }
Catch { Return $False }

# Variables
#$Server = @{Label="Server";Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}} # There is already a "host" built-in
$Process = @{Label="Process";Expression={'Distribution Status'}}
$Measurement = "DistributionPoints"
$TagList = "DistributionPoint","Process"
$MetricList = "Installed","InProgress","Errors","Unknown"

# Output
$Result | Select-Object $Process,@{N='DistributionPoint';E={$_.DistributionPoint.Split(".")[0]}},Installed,InProgress,Errors,Unknown | ConvertTo-Metric -Measure $Measurement -MetricProperty $MetricList -TagProperty $TagList | ConvertTo-InfluxLineString -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to make it work. I believe it had to do with adding DistributionPoint in GROUP BY and calling it in ALIAS BY through "$tag_DistributionPoint" which would give me a null value before... but now it worked.

[image]